# regex to match letter+number as a seperate word (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regexp:

- (a|b|c|d|k)\s?-?\d{1,2}

https://regex101.com/r/r82AyN/2/

It is more or less correct. It should match: `letter a,b,c,d or k with one or two numbers`. Examples are:

- a1
- k12
- a-2
- a1. // should match
- a1 test // should match

But the problem is that it should match only those items that are as separate word, but not within a word. For instance, it should not match these:

- abolsa1
- a1slikti
- abolsa 124
- abols a12ab
- vērtība 428

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\b` for detecting word boundaries:

```
\b(a|b|c|d|k)\s?-?\d{1,2}\b
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\b` to match word boundaries!

```
\b(a|b|c|d|k)\s?-?\d{1,2}\b
```

I basically added `\b` at the end and start of your original regex. This means that the start and end must be a word boundary.

You can think of a word boundary as

```
(?<=\w)(?=\W)|(?<=\W)(?=\w)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r82AyN/3)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your regex in `\b`, that will mean a word boundary at the beginning and the end.

Also, use a character class instead of the group, it is much more efficient:

```
\b[abcdk]\s?-?\d{1,2}\b
```

Try it online [here](https://regex101.com/r/XN2RPv/1).

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are great here. Thought I'd add mine which is slightly different but uses the word boundary `\b` concept too

`\b[abcdk]-?\d{1,2}\b`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DlNvrW/1)